# How to dynamically add my Usercontrols to the Pivot Item in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an Windows Phone 7 App and I am new to it. Now I was stuck at a point. I have a Pivot Control which list all my groups. In each group (Pivot item) I want to show the number of peoples in each group. To show the list of peoples I created a usercontrols with some style. How to dynamically add this usercontrol with loaded data (say image, name, mobilenumber etc) into the pivot item using C#.

```
   <controls:Pivot x:Name="pvGroupList" ItemsSource="{Binding listFriends}" Height="640" Margin="8,126,0,0" Title="Groups" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" FontFamily="/AutoEGreetings;component/Fonts/mrsmonsteracad.ttf#Mrs. Monster Academy" FontSize="29.333">
        <controls:Pivot.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF80FD75" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF80FD75" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.522"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </controls:Pivot.Foreground>
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" FontSize="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer Height="540">
                    <StackPanel>
                        // Here i need to add my list of usercontrol                  
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>          
    </controls:Pivot>
```

I have a Class List in code behind.

```
List<FriendsListDto> listFriends = e.Result;
pvGroupList.ItemsSource = listFriends;
```

Group Headings are binding as expected. But how to bind the usercontrol?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the DataContext of the FriendsListItemsLeft? What property on your user control are you trying to set through binding?

Comment: @ShaharPrish I updated my question. Its not meant that i need to set DataContext in my usercontrol. What i need is to set there a collection of usercontrol items based on group name.

Comment: What is the property on your usercontrol that takes the list? What is the property on FriendsListDto that is the list?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
<controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer Height="540">
            <StackPanel>
                // Here i need to add my list of usercontrol
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

you can use something like that:

```
<controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding YourControlsCollection}/>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

or you can use ItemsControl (instead of ListBox) with ScrollViewer around it.

Instead of List it's better to use ObservableCollection (but it's not necessary, if binding works correctly). And for YourControlsCollection it's better to use ObservableCollection in your FriendsListDto class.

Then just add some elements in your collection of controls and add new element in the listFriends.